# How to make objects as particles face object normals?

Tags: particles, geometry-nodes

I have a collection of objects (2 thorns)
They are used as particles (hair) on a mesh object (thorn crown)
It would be better to have it as a curve, but as far as I know, particle systems don't work with curves.

- How can I make multiple objects such as these thorns appear in random order,
  size, and not in Groups? (The objects are not separate, always appear
  in pairs)
- How can I make the thorns face outwards in alignment with the
  object's normals?

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: any reason you're not using [Geometry Nodes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/geometry_nodes/introduction.html)? it's much easier.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Can you show how to do this with geometry nodes? thx

Answer (score 1):

It's actually easier to do in Geometry Nodes. In this example I have this simple setup with a Bezier circle to which I add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier and use a Thorn object as the instance.

[image]

And then use this node setup:

[image]

You can also use the *Collection Info* node to have more random instances. Here we have two (2) thorn instances:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I'll jump into this and start learning it. :)

Comment: np! i forgot to let you know that there is also the Collection Info node, you can use for more than 1 instance. here you can use 2 or more thorns in the same collection. see update.

Comment: Thanks! So, I'm a bit stuck. Did it like yours, but my thorns go through the stem. And is it possible to orient them along the stem's longitudinal axis as they have an elongated shape like real thorns? If they are rotated their bases kind of hang off. See picture.
Also, the stem and the thorns have subdiv and solidify mods on them as it will be 3d printed.

Comment: you have 4 of those curve objects entangled right? each obj needs its own geometry node modifier. and make sure the origin is at the base of the thorn. oh and looks like mqbaka mqbaka has posted a supplementary answer to help u fix ur problem

Comment: Thanks. It's seems like more than 1 curve but it's just one continuous curve. I rotated them according to mqbaka's suggestion but the thorns are still going through the stem like right in the center

Comment: ah cool. but in your pic i see that the origin (orange dot) is in the center of the thorn instead of the base.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Now it's base in on the stem! :) Do you have a solution for the longitudinal orientation (z axis rotation)? Also, the stem is starting from thick to thin so my goal is to have the thorn objects reduce in size as they grow in different parts of the wide/narrow part of the stem. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

As @HaryMcKenzie stated in his answer, Geometry Nodes is best for this kind of thing but I still want to point out a way to correct your setup.

For some reason, Blender has always aligned the Y-axis with the face normal when rendering an object as particle wich leads to a result like in your setup here where the spikes are leaning on the surface.

To correct that, just tab to edit mode and rotate your spikes on the X-axis by -90degrees with <kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>-90</kbd>. Or you can rotate them in object mode by the same amount and then **apply** the rotation.

If your spikes look like this (pointing to the positive Y direction) :

[image],

then they should look fine on the model :

[image]

Just don't forget to apply the rotation if you rotated them in object mode.

For the collection part, you just have to uncheck `Whole Collection` (which tells Blender to use the whole collection as on strand of hair) and check `Pick Random` (which tells Blender to pick one object from the collection each time):

[image]

The `Use Count` option allows you to specify how often each object of the collection should be picked.